# Cannot Ping from Cisco 3650 to Workstation

Tags: cisco, routing, network, ping

I have a Cisco 3650 that doesn't seem to be able to communicate with one particular workstation for some reason and I am at a loss to figure out why and hope someone can give me a suggestion.  I have a flat network like the following:

```
                             -------- PC (OK)
                             |
Switch 2 ---------- Switch 1 -------- PC (Times out)
                             |
                             -------- PC (OK)
```

Now switch 1 can ping the PC fine but switch 2 cannot.  Switch 2 can ping other PCs that are also connected off of switch 1.

I cannot find any valid reason why switch 1 would ping OK but switch 2 cannot.

I am not sure what information you might need but I will post whatever config is required.

EDIT:

Switch 2 Config:

https://pastebin.com/YNrk1947

Switch 1 Config:

https://pastebin.com/TcFVprQA

Switch 2 connects from port Gi1/1/1 to port Gi1/0/48 switch 1.  The PC in question is actually 2 more hops away on two other switches.  As things work fine from switch 1 I haven't included them but can if need be

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the switch configurations, otherwise we can only speculate or guess, which is off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks, I have included links to to configs on Pastebin as the post is too long otherwise.

Comment: What VLAN are the PCs on?

Comment: Thanks for the assist!  Unfortunately you would not have been able to solve the issue as I had hidden the mac addresses stickyed to the ports in my config listing.  This was ultimately the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.  I connected the offending PC directly to the problem switch and still couldn't ping it.  At this point I realized it must be an issue with the switch so I connected to it from another PC and noticed that the PC had a static mac address attached to gi1/0/1 in the mac address table instead of having a dynamic mac address.  It was then that I realized that the mac address had been set as sticky port security on gi1/0/1.  Once I cleared that, everything worked fine again.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks... Forgot to come back and mark it as you have to wait 3 days to answer your own question.